# Design and Technical issue in Multi Threaded Application

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wanted to Discuss the Design and technical issue/challenges related with multi threaded application.

**Issue I faced**
1.I came across the situation where there is multiple thread is using the shared function/variable crash the application, so proper guard is required on that occasion.
2. State Machine and Multi thread-

There are several point one should remember before delve in to the multi thread application.
There  can issue related to 1. Memory   2. Handle 3. Socket etc.

please share your experience on the following point

1. what are the common mistake one do in the multi threaded application
2. Any specific issue related to multi threaded.
3. Should we pass data by value or by referen in the thread function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are so many...

1) Shared functions/procedures - they are just code and, unless the code modifies itself, there can be no problem.  Local variables are no problem because each thread calls on a separate stack, (amost by definition:).  Any other data can an issue and may need protection.  99.99% of all household API calls on multiTasking OS are thread-safe, again, almost by definition.  Another poster has already warned about thread-local storage...

2) State machines.  Can be a little awkward. You can easly lock all the events firing into the SM, so ensuring the integrity of the state, but you must not make blocking calls from inside the SM while it is locked, (might seem obvious, but I have done this.. once :).

I occasionally run state-machines from one thread only, queueing event objects to it.  This moves the locking to the input queue and means that the SM is somewhat easier to debug. It also means that the thread running the SM can implement timeouts on an internal delta queue and so itself fire timeout calls to the objects on the delta queue, (classic example: TCP server sockets with connection timeouts - thousands of socket objects that each need an independent timeout).

3) 'Should we pass data by value or by referen in the thread function.'.  Not sure what you mean, here.  Most OS allow one pointer to be passed on thread creation - do with it what you will.  You could pass it an event it should signal on work completion or a queue object upon which it is to wait for work requests.   After creation, you need some form of inter-thread comms to send requests and get results, (unless you are going to use the direct 'read/write/waitForExit' mechanism - AV/deadlock/noClose generator).

I usually use a simple semaphore/CS producer-consumer queue to send/receive comms objects between worker threads, and the PostMessage API to send them to a UI thread. Apart from the locking in the queue, I don't often need any more locking.  You have to try quite hard to deadlock a threaded system based on message-passing and things like thread pools become trivial - just make [no. of CPU] threads and pass each one the same queue to wait on.

Common mistakes.  See the other posters for many, to which I would add:

a) Reading/writing directly to thread fields to pass parameters and return results, (esp. between UI threads and 'worker' threads), ie 'Create thread suspended, load parameters into thread fields, resume thread, wait on thread handle for exit, read results from thread fields, free thread object'.  This causes performance hit from continually creating/terminating/destroying threads and often forces the developer to ensure that thread are terminated when exiting an app to prevent AV/216/217 exceptions on close. This can be very tricky, in some cases impossible because a few API's block with no way of unblocking them.  If developers would stop this nasty practice, there would be far fewer app close problems.

b) Trying to build multiThreaded apps in a procedural fashion, eg. trying to wait for results from a work thread in a UI event handler.  Much safer to build a thread request object, load it with parameters, queue it to a work thread and exit the event handler.  The thread can get the object, do work, put results back into the object and, (on Windows, anyway), PostMessage the object back.  A UI message-handler can deal with the results and dispose of the object, (or recycle, reuse:).  This approach means that, since the UI and worker are always operating on different data that can outlive them both, no locking and, (usually), no need to ensure that the work thread is freed when closing the app, (problems with this are ledgendary).

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue people face in multi threading applications are [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing), [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) and not using [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) of some sort to protect globally accessible variables.

Comment: I have one question! If thread updates value we require some kind guarding mechanism.what about thread which do not update the value however reads it only.do you think here also guard is required

Comment: The guards are called Semaphores or mutexes. Even if you only read the variable, you can have problems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrepeatable_reads

Comment: Some time Terminate/kill thread do not work and return false.So how to ensure smooth closer of the thread if one need to Close the thread while it is running.

Comment: That is a pretty big design question, you need to be sure that the thread cleans up after itself but there are so many things you need to look at as well. I would recommend looking at each thing individually.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing these problems when using thread locks.
Deadlock
Priority Inversion
Convoying
“Async-signal-safety”
Kill-tolerant availability
Preemption tolerance
Overall performance

If you want to look at more advanced threading techniques you can look at the lock free threading, where many threads work on the same problem in case they are waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks, memory corruption (of shared resources) due to lack of proper synchronization, buffer overflow (even that can be occured due to memory corruption), improper usage of thread local storage are the most common things

Also it depends on under which platform and technology you're using to implement the thread. For e.g. in Microsoft Windows, if you use MFC objects, several MFC objects are not really shareable across threads because they're heavily rely on thread local storage (e.g CSocket, CWnd classes etc.)